Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics (Chuang Chong Chen) Chapter 1, Problem 27
Let $S \equiv \left\{1,2,\ldots,n +1 \right\}$ where $n \geq 2$ and let
$$
T \equiv \left\{\left(x,y,z\right) \in S^{3} \mid x < z, y < z \right\}
$$
$$
\mbox{Show that}\quad
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2} = \left\vert T\right\vert =
\binom{n + 1}{2} + 2\binom{n + 1}{3}
$$

I was able to show that the RHS is true using a simple combinatorial argument.
However, I do not know how to show the LHS.

I would like some help or a hint please.

Again, a combinatorial argument.  Consider breaking cases based on what value $z$ takes.  Choose a value for $x$ and choose a value for $y$ that satisfy the conditions based on what $z$ is.

Thank you very much. I have completed the problem and posted the solution!

We will use another combinatorial argument to prove the L.H.S. Let's choose a $z$ value first. Since $x$ and $y$ are less than $z$, and $x$ and $y$ can take the same value, we can choose $z$ from the set $\{2,3,\dots,n+1\}$. Then, we choose $x$, and $y$ based on what we chose for $z$. For example, if we choose $n+1$ for $z$, then we can choose from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for $x$ and $y$. More generally, $x,y \in \{1,2,\dots,z-1\}$. We will have $(z-1)^2$ choices for $x$ and $y$ because they can be identical. Thus, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{z=2}^{n+1} (z-1)^2\\
    &= \sum_{z=1}^{n} z^2 \hspace{0.1in} \blacksquare
\end{align*}$$
